# How to save content of ArrayList to the file?

Tags: c#, arraylist, savefiledialog

How to save content of ArrayList to the file? I am working with the following code but ToString() only display a name.

**Edit**

Other thing I have forgotten mention. I am storing the data as encrypted. The only thing I have problem with is getting the whole content of ArrayList and pass it to encryption method.

Examples for dummies recommended.

**SaveFile() method**

```
private void SaveFile()
{
    sfdSaveFile.FileName = storedAuth.UserName;
    sfdSaveFile.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    sfdSaveFile.RestoreDirectory = true;
    sfdSaveFile.Filter = "AES Binary Files (*.abf)|*.sbf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    sfdSaveFile.DefaultExt = ".abf";
    sfdSaveFile.FilterIndex = 1;

    sfdSaveFile.ShowDialog();
}
```

**Save File Dialog**

```
private void sfdSaveToLocation_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    EncryptDecrypt en = new EncryptDecrypt();
    AddEntryWindow addWindow = new AddEntryWindow
                (this, storedAuth.UserName, storedAuth.Password);


    // how to save it appropriately?
    string encrypted = en.Encrypt(addWindow.addedEntry.ToString(),
        storedAuth.UserName, storedAuth.Password);

    File.WriteAllText(sfdSaveFile.FileName, encrypted);
}
```

Comment: you want to look into serialization http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx

Comment: Is addWindow.addedEntry is the arrayList you are talking about? Is yes, then you will have to enumerate over the collection, rather than calling ToString() method directly on the arraylist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Serialization can be good idea this method will convert array to string (the type of array item should be serialiazable)

```
public string arrayToString(System.Collections.ArrayList ar)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings st = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
    st.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    st.Indent = false;
    System.Xml.XmlWriter w = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sb, st);
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer s = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(ar.GetType());
    s.Serialize(w, ar);
    w.Close();
    return sb.ToString();        
}

public static void SaveArraytoFile(System.Collections.ArrayList ar, string fileName)
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        foreach (var item in ar)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems interesting. I will take a look at it when I get chance. Thanks.

Comment: I edited and the method and removed var ns = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "AC");

Comment: `XmlWriter` is `IDisposable` so you should be `using` it - won't make any difference in your example but it's a good habit to get into (imho).

Comment: Yes I should do that,thx for putting stress on it, now I would never forgot that

Comment: I got error InvalidOperationException was unhanded by user code at line: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer s = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(this.GetType());

Comment: chnage this.GetType() to ar.GetType()

Comment: Ok, not there is similar problem but also say that there is a problem while creating xml document at line: s.Serialize(w, ar); You are my favorite person today :D No joke!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the type. All elements in the array are string.

Comment: Ok ,if it is array of string i put another function can help you